# Query is not using Index

Tags: query-optimization, informix

Following is my query with complete explain plan and when I taking the explain plan, its giving sequential scan on ach_batches.ach_batch_date where as the index is present on the table's mentioned column. Further, the problem is enough IO peaks observed on DB server otherwise query performance is not bad.

```
QUERY: (OPTIMIZATION TIMESTAMP: 01-23-2021 04:23:45)        (FIRST_ROWS OPTIMIZATION)

------
SELECT
    ach_batches.ach_batch_sr_no,
    ach_batches.ach_origin_id,
    ach_batches.odfi_routing_no,
    ach_batches.ach_batch_date,
    ach_batches.company_name,
    ach_batches.ach_tot_dr_amount,
    ach_batches.ach_tot_cr_amount,
    ach_batch_details.ach_batch_rec_no,
    ach_batch_details.trans_id,
    ach_batch_details.ach_trans_code,
    ach_batch_details.rdfi_routing_no,
    ach_batch_details.dfi_account_no,
    ach_batch_details.amount,
    ach_batch_details.receiver_id,
    ach_batch_details.receiver_name,
    ach_batch_details.ach_bat_ret_code,
    transaction_types.trans_type_abrv,
    b_settle_statuses.name
FROM
    ( ( ach_batches ach_batches
INNER JOIN ach_batch_details ach_batch_details
ON
    ach_batches.ach_batch_sr_no=ach_batch_details.ach_batch_sr_no )
INNER JOIN transaction_types transaction_types
ON
    ach_batch_details.trans_type=transaction_types.trans_type )
INNER JOIN b_settle_statuses b_settle_statuses
ON
    ach_batch_details.settle_status=b_settle_statuses.status
WHERE
    (
        (
            ach_batches.ach_batch_date >= '01/09/2021'
        )
    )
AND
    (
        (
            ach_batches.ach_batch_date <= '01/10/2021'
        )
    )
ORDER BY
    ach_batches.ach_batch_sr_no,
    ach_batch_details.ach_batch_rec_no

Estimated Cost: 46114
Estimated # of Rows Returned: 1
Temporary Files Required For: Order By  

  1) hfarooq.ach_batches: SEQUENTIAL SCAN

        Filters: (hfarooq.ach_batches.ach_batch_date >= 01/09/2021 AND hfarooq.ach_batches.ach_batch_date <= 01/10/2021 ) 

  2) hfarooq.ach_batch_details: INDEX PATH

    (1) Index Name: informix. 122_103
        Index Keys: ach_batch_sr_no ach_batch_rec_no   (Serial, fragments: ALL)
        Lower Index Filter: hfarooq.ach_batches.ach_batch_sr_no = hfarooq.ach_batch_details.ach_batch_sr_no 
NESTED LOOP JOIN

  3) hfarooq.transaction_types: INDEX PATH

    (1) Index Name: mcp. 323_850
        Index Keys: trans_type   (Serial, fragments: ALL)
        Lower Index Filter: hfarooq.ach_batch_details.trans_type = hfarooq.transaction_types.trans_type 
NESTED LOOP JOIN

  4) hfarooq.b_settle_statuses: INDEX PATH

    (1) Index Name: mcp. 2420_8748
        Index Keys: status   (Serial, fragments: ALL)
        Lower Index Filter: hfarooq.ach_batch_details.settle_status = hfarooq.b_settle_statuses.status 
NESTED LOOP JOIN
```

Table's index:
[image]

[image]

Comment: How many records are in the `ach_batches` table?  How many different values are in the `ach_batch_date` column?

Comment: 200366 total rows
& only 2 different values of ach_batch_date i.e two dates only

Comment: Perhaps my second question did not come across correctly.  I mean to ask how many different date values exist _in the table_, not in the query.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have added a more photo. I hope this will come to you correctly. Sorry for my wrong interpretation.

Comment: Please edit your post to include the EXPLAIN PLAN.

Comment: If I'm understanding what you've included, the filter you have on the table shows that it won't filter any rows at all, so it's actually faster to sequential scan rather than going to the index and then fetching the data row.  If you had a more selective filter, the query should switch to using the index.

Comment: @AndyLester check now. I have added complete explain plan.

Comment: The `WHERE` clause is completely moot, since it won't filter off any records at all.

Comment: Then, how can I avoid that consumption of IO? Should I use directive index?

Comment: What isolation level is the query running at?  If you are running with dirty read, it could be the query is doing a light scan, which bypasses the buffer pool.  If you are not using dirty read, then how big is your buffer pool?  So how many pages of all the tables/indexes in the query will fit in the buffer pool cache?

Comment: It looks like a recent version of Informix — what is the version number and the platform it is running on?  In the old days, the first question would be "Have you run UPDATE STATISTICS?".  These days, with AUS — Automatic Update Statistics — this is much less often a problem/solution.  Nevertheless, it might be a part of the answer.  Are the counts for the two days the only dates in the table (you show ~200k rows for 2021-01-10 and ~200 rows for 2021-01-09)?